# Jest automock not applied to a module

Tags: typescript, mocking, jestjs

I've run into trouble running Jest tests for my modules - I have a simple entry-point class:

```js
import { Callback, CloudFrontRequestEvent, Context, Handler } from "aws-lambda";

import { CloudFrontHandler } from "./CloudFrontHandler";
import { OriginClient } from "./OriginClient";
import { ResponseRenderer } from "./ResponseRenderer";
import { TemplateRenderer } from "./TemplateRenderer";

export class LambdaHandler {
    private readonly renderer: TemplateRenderer;

    constructor(renderer: TemplateRenderer) {
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }

    public handle: Handler = (event: CloudFrontRequestEvent, _: Context, callback: Callback): void => {
        console.log(new CloudFrontHandler(null, null)); // <- just an empty object here! CloudFrontHandler {}
        console.log(new OriginClient(null)); // <- properly mocked
        console.log(new ResponseRenderer(null, null)); // <- properly mocked
        new CloudFrontHandler(
            new OriginClient(event.Records[0].cf.request),
            new ResponseRenderer(callback, this.renderer),
        )
            .handle(); // <- because CloudFrontHandler is not mocked, an error occurs here
    }
}
```

For whatever reason `CloudFrontHandler` class does not get mocked (`OriginClient` and `ResponseRenderer` are properly auto-mocked). Following is my test class:

```js
import "jest";
import { Callback, CloudFrontRequest, CloudFrontRequestEvent } from "aws-lambda";
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils";
import { LambdaHandler, TemplateRenderer } from "../../../main/nodejs";

import { CloudFrontHandler } from "../../../main/nodejs/edge/CloudFrontHandler";
import { OriginClient } from "../../../main/nodejs/edge/OriginClient";
import { ResponseRenderer } from "../../../main/nodejs/edge/ResponseRenderer";

jest.mock("../../../main/nodejs/edge/CloudFrontHandler");
jest.mock("../../../main/nodejs/edge/OriginClient");
jest.mock("../../../main/nodejs/edge/ResponseRenderer");

const MockedCloudFrontHandler = mocked(CloudFrontHandler);
const MockedOriginClient = mocked(OriginClient);
const MockedResponseRenderer = mocked(ResponseRenderer);

describe("LambdaHandler", (): void => {
        it("should handle CloudFront request", (): void => {
                const templateRenderer: TemplateRenderer = {} as TemplateRenderer;
                const callback: Callback = jest.fn() as Callback;
                const request: CloudFrontRequest = {} as CloudFrontRequest;
                const event: CloudFrontRequestEvent = {
                    Records: [
                        {
                            cf: {
                                request: request,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                } as CloudFrontRequestEvent;

                let handler: LambdaHandler = new LambdaHandler(templateRenderer);
                handler.handle(event, null, callback)
                // todo

                expect(MockedCloudFrontHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
                expect(MockedOriginClient).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
                expect(MockedResponseRenderer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        });
});
```

(I keep source files and test files separately, thus all of these `src/main` `src/test` paths)

Any reason why Jest wouldn't mock this one module class?

-edit-

The error message is:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).handle is not a function
```

Comment: What version of NodeJS are you using? I believe I may have seen the same problem [here](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/issues/3247), but only on NodeJS 11.x. Older versions of NodeJS work fine.

Comment: I use exactly 11.0.0.

Comment: Tried with 10.13 and 8.15 - same behavior.

Comment: https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/998 Is this related?

Comment: Could please add a sample of how `handle` is defined in `CloudFrontHandler`?

Comment: @10101010 You probably just pointed me towards the root cause - it's an arrow function, so in TypeScript it's translated to JavaScript as a property assigned in constructor. I'll check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments under my question pointed me to the root cause - the issue here is, that `CloudFrontHandler.handle` is an arrow function, which TypeScript translates into property assigned in a constructor. Since the constructor is auto-mocked, the function is not assigned. Creating manual mock for the `.handle()` method solves the problem.